# Can't run/debug play framework 2.6 unit tests with intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit, playframework

I downloaded play-java-starter-example and I am trying to run(and debug)  the unit tests in UnitTest.java. didn't make any changes to the project. just imported the build.sbt to intellij

I am using Intellij 2018.2.4 and I have the play & scala plugins installed

When running the test (through intellij) I get this result:

```
objc[33267]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x1032414c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1042744e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "UnitTest"Empty test suite.
```

when I try to debug I get this:

```
objc[33246]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10d4184c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x10d4f34e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54064', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54064', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "UnitTest"Empty test suite.
```

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: posted the issue on youTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-14455